# How to execute a program by name on command-line without typing current directory?

Tags: unix, path

On my last UNIX setup, I was able to simply type a binary's name if I was in the same directory and it would execute it. However on this new setup, I have to preface binary names with ./ if I want to execute them. Anyone know how to circumvent this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conventional way to address this (and probably the way it was done on your previous setup) is to add `.` to your `PATH` environment variable.  So if your `PATH` is `/usr/bin:/bin`, then add `.` to the end (along with the `:` separator) so you have `/usr/bin:/bin:.`.  Exactly how to do that varies by shell.  A quick Google will no doubt get you the answer for your shell.

Do be aware that there are potential negative security implications to that, though, especially on a shared service.  If an attacker manages to get an evil file in a directory where you are, and to name that file a normally-innocuous command (like `ls`), they could cause you to unintentionally run the evil file.

For this reason, if you are going to do this, at least make sure you put `.` as the last item in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using the default shell and that the shell is bash.

Edit: /etc/bashrc and add this:

export set PATH=$PATH:.